# сортировка в зависимости от того что было раньше create или update

Tags: mysql, sql

В таблице есть поля

```
id|name(уникальное)|create|update
```

приложение вставляет запись с пометкой текущего времени в create или обновляет существующую с записью времени в поле update.

Как отсортировать таблицу по времени, в зависимости от того что было ПОЗЖЕ create или update?

Comment: `order by least(create, update)`

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за подсказку, только нужно в обратном порядке отсортировать

Comment: дак `desc` добавьте и будет в обратном или замените на `greatest`

Comment: *приложение вставляет запись с пометкой текущего времени в create или обновляет существующую с записью времени в поле update* Дикая какая-то логика... данные могут свидетельствовать о том, что запись обновлена до того, как её вставили?

Comment: Прошу прощения о ошибся в вопросе, нужно сортировать по тому что было позже!